# List Filename and current date of all files in a directory

Tags: powershell

I am using the below command to get filename and current date

```
Get-childitem -path c:\folder\2010 | select -property filename , currenttime
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Filename             Current date
c:\folder\2010\txt1
c:\folder\2010\txt2
```

But I need to print with current date is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean you want each file to appear with the date/time that you executed the file scan or some property of the file, such as last write time, etc?

Comment: Yes that's right. File name and execution

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-childitem -path c:\folder\2010 | select -property fullname, @{n='Current date';e={get-date}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `filename` be `fullname` by the way (although OP used `filename` in their question)?

Comment: Yes its full name

Comment: Its generating the execution date along with full filename and path 